# Breadcrumb displays query string

Tags: php, breadcrumbs

I would like my breadcrumb script to display the page name only(example: [pic](http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/8009/4gm8.png)), instead of page name + query string if exists(example: [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M1NW.png)).
This is my breadcrumb script:

```
<?php
$crumbs = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
foreach($crumbs as $crumb){
    echo '<li class="active">';
    echo ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_",),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');
    echo '</li>';
}
?>
```

How do I exclude everything after ".php"?
Thank you for your help

Comment: so u need site/activate only?

Comment: yeah I want to exclude everything that is not a pagetitle from the breadcrumb

Comment: `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];`

Answer (score 1):

use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function for getting the parts of the url

You may use this after some editing

```
<?php
$parsed=parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$crumbs = explode("/",$parsed['path']);

print_r(parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
foreach($crumbs as $crumb){
    echo '<li class="active">';
    echo ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_",),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');
    echo '</li>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$crumbs = explode("/",$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
$html="";
foreach($crumbs as $crumb){
    $crumb = ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb));
    if(trim($crumb)!=""){
        $html .= '<li class="active">'.$crumb.'</li>';
    }
}
$html = "<li>".ucfirst($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"])."</li>".$html;
echo $html;
```

?>